# Parsing XML File with Python, while extracting Attributes and Children

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to read an XML file in Python whose general format is as follows:

```
<item id="1149" num="1" type="topic">
    <title>Afghanistan</title>
    <additionalInfo>Afghanistan</additionalInfo>
</item>
```

(This snippet repeats many times.)

I'm trying to get the `id` value and the `title` value to be printed into a file. 
Currently, I'm having trouble with getting the XML file into Python. Currently, I'm doing this to get the XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://api.npr.org/list?id=3002' #1007 is science
response = urlopen(url)
f = open('out.xml', 'w')
f.write(response)
```

However, whenever I run this code, I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 9, in <module> TypeError: expected a character buffer object`, which makes me think that I'm not using something that can handle XML. 
Is there any way that I can save the XML file to a file, then extract the `title` of each section, as well as the `id` attribute associated with that title?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `response.read()` not `response`. The response variable is an instance not the xml string. By doing `response.read()` it will read the xml from the response instance.

You can then write it directly to a file like so:

```
url = 'http://api.npr.org/list?id=3002' #1007 is science
response = urlopen(url)
f = open('out.xml', 'w')
f.write(response.read())
```

Alternatively you could also parse it directly into the ElementTree like so:

```
url = 'http://api.npr.org/list?id=3002' #1007 is science
response = urlopen(url)
tree = ET.fromstring(response.read())
```

To extract all of the id/title pairs you could do the following as well:

```
url = 'http://api.npr.org/list?id=3002' #1007 is science
response = urlopen(url)
tree = ET.fromstring(response.read())
for item in tree.findall("item"):
    print item.get("id")
    print item.find("title").text
```

From there you can decide where to store/output the values

Answer (score 1):

You can read the content of response by this code :

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
response= opener.open("http://api.npr.org/list?id=3002").read()
opener.close()
```

and then write it to file :

```
f = open('out.xml', 'w')
f.write(response)
f.close()
```